# Allow registering user to select post category when signing up to blog

Tags: posts, categories, user-registration

Is it possible that when a user registers to become a blogger (either at Author or Contributor level) that they can select a blog category to start blogging in from a dropdown?

For example: User A signs up to become a premium blogger on blogging platform xyz. During the signup process he/she selects from a dropdown the post category (lets say 'photography') that will be their main category. Wordpress will remember this and the user will be placed into that selected category.

I cannot find anything anywhere on the web to help me here (Im a rookie at this so may be searching the wrong thing)

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new field in the registration form [Customizing the Registration Form](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Registration_Form) after that, you can add a function to the `save_post` action with `add_action('save_post', 'set_category_by_username');` to set the category of the `current` user to the post.